# How to upload image on firebase without button android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How to upload the image without "upload" button and to use that new image automatically as default user picture? How can I implement this in my code.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    circlePic = findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(circlePic);

 public void Profile(View view) {
    Intent cpicview = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(cpicview, 1);
} 



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageRIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageRIntent);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        mProfileUri = imageRIntent.getData();
    Uri selectedImage = imageRIntent.getData();
    this.circlePic.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

Comment: what do you mean without upload button? It should be like this, you click on a view widget=>go to gallery=>select a photo=> go back to activity and photo is set to an imageview=>set the uri to the place where you save the user info in db

Comment: Sir i mean ... Tap on image view>select new picture> upload right after selection

Answer (score 0):

first add click listener to your imageview that will open activity to choose an image

```
profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setType("image/*");
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Profile Image"), REQUEST_CODE);
   }        
});
```

then implement **onActivityResult** that will be executed when image is selected

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            uploadImage(bitmap);
    }
}
```

this is the method to upload Bitmap

```
private void uploadImage(Bitmap bitmap) 
{
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("Your url for storage");
    StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/" + chat_id + Utils.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            Log.d(downloadUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

and don't forget to declare **REQUEST_CODE** in your class

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

and maybe you will need to add this line in your xml for your profile image view

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: i am confused with your code sir, 
as i am using glide, how can i implement the upload method as you shown your code? i tried it but it doesnt work.
sorry in advance if i am asking too much